# How can i setup lighting in Eevee?

Tags: light, texture-painting, eevee-render-engine, scene

Im doing texture painting in Eevee, and I use lookdev mode. But i dont have a world shader and whenever i add any kind of light it doesn't make a change to my scene. What do i need to add / change in my world shader to be able to modify my lighting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable your world shader in the *Viewport Shading* tab.

Check *Scene World* to use your environment texture.
Check *Scene Lights* if you want your lights to show in LookDev mode.

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much :) I will try it.

Comment: Happy to help :). Hope it works for you.